# Linux - Why does my executable have libpthread as a shared library?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile

So basically I´d like to know why my executable has libpthread as a shared library whilst my code is not using any threading functions whatsoever. It isn´t included from the makefile either. Is it because GCC is compiled by default with "--enable-threads=posix" ?

If so is there a way to remove it from my executable? If not what is the problem?

**ldd**

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x0000656150c5a000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000656150a4c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000656150746000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00006561504c1000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00006561502ab000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000065614ff17000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x000065614fcf9000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000656150c5b000)
```

**Makefile**

```
CC = gcc
OFLAGS = -O3

C++ = g++ -g
LFLAGS = -lrt

# API Exclusions
DFLAGS = -DNO_ZLIB -DNO_LOCALIZATION -DNO_INTERFACE

CFLAGS = $(OFLAGS) $(DFLAGS) -I. -I../rgapi/include/core/ -I../rgapi/include/public/

OBJS = ( ... list of .o files ... )
PROGS = ./rgs

all: $(OBJS) $(PROGS)

./rgs: $(OBJS)
    $(C++) -o ./rgs $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(PROGS)

$(OBJS): %.o: %.cpp
    $(C++) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -c $<

./rgs: $(OBJS)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are linking with `librt.so`:

```
LFLAGS = -lrt
```

This is an indirect dependency.

```
$ ldd /usr/lib64/librt.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcc33d2000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2480a0b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2480649000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000562f4cffb000)
```

`librt.so` is linked with `-lpthread`. If you link with any shared library, you inherit all the baggage that the shared library gets linked with.

You cannot "remove it from your executable". The only way to do so is not link with `-lrt`.

Comment: Oh wow seriously ... Ok I didn´t check librt, because I didn´t think it´d have libpthread as a dependency. Okay ... I only link -lrt because the exe measures time for interval updates in the main loop.

Is there an alternative where I could measure intervals? Usually in the 50ms range for the update loop without having to use clock_gettime, and thus link librt. Which I am doing right now.

Comment: `gettimeofday()` should be sufficient for this purpose.

Comment: I was wondering if you also knew if I should be worried about time updates - I´ve always used CLOCK_MONOTONIC because it´s used in a gaming server and I use the time both for the update interval and to decide when a connection has timed out. Even a few second jumps could be really bad. Should I be disabling the NTP service or do I not have to be worried about this?

Comment: Yes, `gettimeofday()` will report changes to the system clock.